# How can I create a PHP user defined function that is similar to the str_replace()

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo my_own_string_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!");

function my_own_string_replace($find, $replace, $string)
{
//Block of codes?
}
?>
```

This should output: **Hello Peter**

Comment: why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Be more specific - do you not want to use **any** PHP builtins? Just loop over the String? Did you try anything? This looks like homework.

Comment: Why you have to create user define function when inbuilt function is already there

Comment: Yes . It is just a homework . can anyone help me please .
I can only use strlen(), all other built-in functions are not allowed .

I can only use loops and if-else statements . 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: as you say you can only use `strlen()` and `loop` and `if-else`:

```
echo my_own_string_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!");

function my_own_string_replace($find, $replace, $string)
{
      $total_len  = strlen($string);
      $str = "";
      $new_str = "";
      for($i = 0;$i<$total_len;$i++)
      {
            if($string[$i] == " ")
            {
                  $new_str .= $str." ";
                  $str = "";

            }
            else
            {     $str .= $string[$i];
                  if($str == $find)
                  {
                        $str = $replace;
                  }

                  if($i == ($total_len-1))
                        $new_str .= $str;

            }
      }      
      return $new_str;
}
```

[DEMO:](https://eval.in/823418)

Comment: Thank you so much . 
This is the exact solution I'am trying to think of .
Now my homework is done thank you sir ! :)

Comment: If it help you then up-vote it and accept this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thanks for reminding me . 
Any way your solution is almost perfect .
But I found out that when the given parameters are
    echo my_own_string_replace("world","peter","helloworld!");
the result is $new_str = "helloworld" ,
it should be $new_str = "hellopeter" . 

any way thanks again , these codes are good to start with , 
I think I just have to add something to satisfy the problem .

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
function my_own_string_replace($find, $replace, $string)
{
    return implode($replace, explode($find, $string));
}

echo my_own_string_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!");
```

**Output**

```
Hello Peter!
```

Comment: Thanks , It worked but I should not use any built-in functions , 
just nested loops and if-else statements .

Comment: *any built-in functions* - you have to use some built in functions to find, extract etc.

Comment: Sorry , I mean just using strlen() and nested for loops and if-else statements